# My car is sputtering

Tags: troubleshooting, saab

I have a 2004 Saab 9-3. Changed the coils less than a year ago. My car is sputtering when idling and when driving. Started using premium gas at Chevron---thought it was the gasoline. Mileage is 11600.

**Can it be the spark plugs?**   --changed them about one year ago

Comment: Whwn you changed them did you the plugs with the suggested type?

Comment: have you had anyone look at it?  if so, what did they say?  Do you have a check engine light that is on?  does it sputter ALL the time or are there conditions where it runs acceptably, like accelerating hard to get on the freeway.

Answer (score 3):

Sputtering could be fuel, air, or spark.  But yes, spark sounds like a likely culprit.

- Generally fuel related items will generate a check engine light and codes. (You've not mentioned check engine light or codes, so I'm assuming there are none.  If there are Onboard Diagnostics (OBD2) codes you should get those items fixed first.)
- Plugged air filter is not all that likely, you'd have other problems besides sputtering at idle.
- Spark related items are a whole other story. My guess here is bad spark plug wires.  You will have to check each wire from the distributor / ignition system ALL the way to the sparkplugs.  Please pull the wires OFF at both ends and check that nothing is burnt or worn.
- One fun test is to look for spark plug wires shorting out...  You open the hood at night in a dark place, keep all the lights off.  Place the car in park, and start it up.  Then carefully inspect under the hood looking for stray sparks.  Please be careful around moving parts (fan belts, cooling fans, moving alternator.  I got my hand caught in an alternator pulley with cooling blades, at night Twack! and it wasn't a pleasant experience and visit to the emergency room.)
- Another thing to look at is the distributor cap and rotor (Not sure if your car has this or distributorless ignition coils)  I've seen cars with loose caps lately.  The bolts were tight, but the plastic inside had cracked and the cap was loose.
- I really doubt you've got spark plug issues.  Again, my guess is a bad / burnt adapter on one spark plug wire where it is attached to the top of the spark plug.

Update:

- One way cool test is to remove the wiring from each spark plug, one at a time and read the tachometer.  If the engine is idling rough, and you remove one spark plug's wiring, and nothing changes, that circuit is suspect.
- Somebody suggested that you've got a Coil on Plug distribution system.  Way cool.  They still need to be checked between the coil and the top of the spark plug.  If memory serves correctly, Coil On Plug (COP) systems DO indeed set an engine code if the coil itself fails. The code will even tell you which cylinder is not firing.  An great test of the individual coil is to clear the codes swap the coils between different cylinders and retest again.

Let us know what you find.

Comment: Again, you're killing it!  Nice answer  +1

Comment: I've been digging through your answers.  Great stuff!    +1

Comment: Thanks, you can probably tell that I worked for an OEM (Original Equipment Manufacturer) first as a design engineer, and then as a troubleshooter and new launch guy?  It's time to share lessons learned. I tend to focus on the why and how questions a lot.. when you understand how (and why) things work the way they do, it's much easier to fix'em and make improvements.

Comment: IIRC The 9-3 uses COP.

Comment: @zipzit  TOTALLY agree w/ you.  Teach a man to fish.....

Comment: Coil on plug. Awesome. Remove each coil on plug, inspect the botton of the insert where it mates up to the spark plug. I'm guessing one of thoses is shot.  The use of unexplained abreviations are highly offensive...Best practice is to NEVER use them with out first Explaining What They Mean (EWTE).    What's a IIRC ?

Comment: "If I remember correctly"